# TSQL to find if server is listening on dynamic or static port

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-ports

Using TSQL, how can I find if the MS SQL server (any version) is configured to use static port or is it using dynamic port?

Script i am trying to use:

```
DECLARE @TcpPort VARCHAR(5)
        ,@RegKey VARCHAR(100)

IF @@SERVICENAME !='MSSQLSERVER'
    BEGIN
        SET @RegKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + @@SERVICENAME + '\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @RegKey = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP\IPAll'
    END

EXEC master..xp_regread
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    ,@key = @RegKey
    ,@value_name = 'TcpPort'
    ,@value = @TcpPort OUTPUT

EXEC master..xp_regread
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    ,@key = @RegKey
    ,@value_name = 'TcpDynamicPorts'
    ,@value = @TcpPort OUTPUT

SELECT @TcpPort AS PortNumber
        ,@@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
        ,@@SERVICENAME AS ServiceName
```

Comment: For your @@SERVICENAME key, remove the \IPAll from the end of the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can determine which port an instance is using from the error log but not whether its static or dynamic.

```
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 1, 1, 'Server is listening'
```

Alternative would be to read from the registry via xp_regread.

```
DECLARE 
    @StaticPort NVARCHAR(512)
    , @DynamicPort NVARCHAR(512)

EXEC xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll'
    , 'TcpPort'
    , @StaticPort OUTPUT

EXEC xp_regread
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    , 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll'
    , 'TcpDynamicPorts'
    , @DynamicPort OUTPUT

SELECT
    @StaticPort AS StaticPort
    , @DynamicPort AS DynamicPort
```

Comment: xp_regread: is it present in sql server 2008?

Comment: Undocumented and unsupported but yes it is there.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I tried to generalize this for multiple SQL servers but I don't see anything. Did i miss something? Script has been appended to the question

Comment: @Manjot, daft typo in my script above, now corrected. Prefer your version by the way, have filed it away in the script library.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it is possible (theoretically):

- Write [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) (use .NET to read specific data from Windows registry)
- Use [static, dynamic port allocation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) what and [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to read from registry
- Grant all rights to execute this.

Comment: thanks..yes Use static, dynamic port allocation what and how to read from registry sounds appropriate... but how can I know which key to read?

Comment: @Manjot see [SQL Server xp_regread with T-SQL](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2008/08/manipulating-re.html)

Answer (score 1):

another way to find which port sql server is using is through the DMV called [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as per the script below.

```
--===============================
-- sys.dm_exec_connections
--===============================
SELECT 
[user]=suser_sname()
,local_tcp_port
,session_id
,connect_time
,net_transport
,protocol_type
,encrypt_option
,auth_scheme
,last_read
,last_write

FROM   sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
GO
```